# Active link with PHP

Tags: php, navigation, hyperlink, nav

I have been reading lots of posts about this issue but I couldnt reach to a good solution so I may need your help on this.

I have a index.php which has a header.php included. The idea would be that when I click on some other page for ex: page2 that the link in the header.php changes to active to the correspondingly page.

Like any other normal navigation should work.=)

At the moment, this is what I have so far and it is not working. Do you know why? Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance,

//in the index.php I have this:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <!--HEADER-->
    <?php include_once("header.php"); ?>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div class="inner-main">
            <!--MAIN-->
            <?php $page = "home"; ?>
            <?php include_once("includes/home.php"); ?>
            <!--MAIN-->
        </div>
    </div><!--mainContainer-->
</div><!--wrapper--></body>
```

//Inside the header.php I have the following:

```
<div id="header">
<div class="inner-header">
    <div class="top-nav">
        <ul id="nav" class="nav clearfix">
            <li class="<?php echo ($page == "home" ? "selected" : "")?>"><a href="home.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="division">&bull;</li>
            <li class="<?php echo ($page == "page2" ? "selected" : "")?>"><a href="page2.php" target="_self">PAGE 2</a></li>
        </ul><!--nav-->
    </div><!--top-nav-->
</div><!--inner-header--></div><!-- header-->
```

//So what if I click on page2 on the top nav? How can I do to view page.php and also the corresponding link be active in the top navigation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `$page` variable before including header.php

index.php:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <!--HEADER-->
    <?php $page = "home"; ?>
    <?php include_once("header.php"); ?>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div class="inner-main">
            <!--MAIN-->

            <?php include_once("includes/home.php"); ?>
            <!--MAIN-->
        </div>
    </div><!--mainContainer-->
</div><!--wrapper-->
```

Comment: $page will ALWAYS be home in this case. if((!isset($page)) {$page = "home"; }

Comment: @Kenzo i mean redefine $page variable on each page pageN.php

Comment: Ramil Amr Ok, that wasn't clear though. You still should be checking to see if the var isset before declaring it.